# Should I check if the 'disabled' attribute exists before removing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style

I had a requirement where I need to clear off the "select all" checkbox in case user manually deselects any of the data rows.
This has been accomplished by detecting this during an `onRowSelect` (jqgrid event) event.
The code snippet is as below and works as expected.

```
onSelectRow: function(){$("input:checkbox[id='cb_jqg']").removeAttr('checked');}
```

The thing I wonder about is whether I should check the checkbox for already selected before I clear it off or can I simply clear it (as it does not have any impact) as done above.

Is there any performance / code ethic issues with the syntax I used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a check before setting the value will be slower than just arbitrarily setting them all simply because it has to *do* the check.

Ethically, it's not gonna throw an error, so all's fair in love and coding, right?

Comment: Thanks for reply. This aligns with my reasoning while I was doing writing the code.
Later I realise that the "select all" state is not that frequent, so will it be better just to have a check to see if its checked (and since more often than not it is not checked) do nothing.
Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have multiple checkboxes with the same `id`. This is invalid in HTML. You could instead use the same `name` for these checkboxes.

Also, the more standard way of setting the checkedness of a checkbox is simply setting the `checked` property of the checkbox element to `true` or `false`, rather than rely on jQuery's attribute handling methods.